# SharePoint Form library template broken after renaming

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, infopath, library

I went in and changed a SharePoint template (*.xsn) which was being used by a document library to create and modify new items.

I thought the safe way would be to rename my new one over the top of the old...but now it won't allow me to create new items or open old ones in the 
library.

If I try to open an old library item now it attempts to open InfoPath and then complains about a domain permission level problem.

How do I link it the library all back to the new template correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try downloading the form and publish it again to SharePoint?

Comment: I did eventually figure this one out and yep, just needed to republish through infopath. I'm learning sharepoint as I go so seemingly simple things are still a challenge. Thanks